# How to push an object from a form to an array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am attempting to add a contact in AngularJS. I am new to Angular and would like to know if I have formatted this correctly for the contact to be added.

```
<div class="row">
  <form ng-submit="addContact(firstName,email,phone)">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="contact.firstName">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="contact.email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="name">Phone:</label>
      <input type="phone" name="phone" ng-model="contact.phone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="submit" value="Add Contact">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <td>{{contact.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

In my app.js

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('contactApp', []);

app.controller('contactController', function($scope){
        $scope.contacts = [{firstName:"Joe",email:"joe@gmail.com",phone:"453-367-9383"}];
        $scope.addContact = function(firstName,email,phone){
        $scope.contacts.push({firstName:'',email:'',phone:''});

        };

    });
}());
```

Comment: why are you pushing empty values in `addContact` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working template. Note that, "track by $index" used in ng-repeat for add possible duplicates.

```js
var app = angular.module('contactApp', []);
app.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
  $scope.aContact = {
    firstName: "Joe",
    email: "joe@gmail.com",
    phone: "453-367-9383"
  };
  $scope.contacts = [];
  $scope.addContact = function(firstName, email, phone) {
    $scope.contacts.push($scope.aContact);
    $scope.aContact = {}; //clear contact after added to contact list
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="contactApp" ng-controller="contactController">
  <div class="row">
    <form ng-submit="addContact()">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="aContact.firstName">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="aContact.email">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="name">Phone:</label>
        <input type="phone" name="phone" ng-model="aContact.phone">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Contact">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <table>
    <th>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index">
        <td>{{contact.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correct key names to call the function. Your inputs are bound to contact.firstName,contact.email,contact.phone.

```
   <form ng-submit="addContact(contact.firstName,contact.email,contact.phone)">
```

Also push the parameters you recieved in you function

```
      $scope.addContact = function(firstName,email,phone){
        $scope.contacts.push({firstName:firstName,email:email,phone:phone});
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make two changes. First one is in `ng-submit` like

```
<form ng-submit="addContact(contact.firstName,contact.email,contact.phone)">
```

second one is in your `addContact` method that should look something like

```
$scope.addContact = function(firstName,email,phone){
        $scope.contacts.push({firstName:firstName,email:email,phone:phone});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the keys, the values you are passing to the function:

```
$scope.addContact = function(firstName,email,phone){
    $scope.contacts.push({firstName:firstName,email:email,phone:phone});
};
```

As well as modify your ng-submit:

```
<form ng-submit="addContact(contact.firstName,contact.email,contact.phone)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the parameters to the function in this case because the fields are already 2-way binded to your controller. Alternative solution:

```
$scope.addContact = function(){
     $scope.contacts.push({
         firstName: $scope.contact.firstName,
         email: $scope.contact.email,
         phone: $scope.contact.phone
     });
     $scope.contact.firstName = '';
     $scope.contact.email = '';
     $scope.contact.phone = '';
};
```

Then, Your form's opening tag should be changed to

```
<form ng-submit="addContact()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the form inside ng-repeat. This will isolate the contact you're editing from all the other contacts and keep them in an array. Maybe tie the addcontact function to a button on ng-click, but get rid of the function arguments since they aren't used.

Answer (score 0):

this is working code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="contactApp">
<head>
</head>
<body  ng-controller="contactController">

<form ng-submit="addContact(contacts)">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="contacts.firstName"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="contacts.email"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="name">Phone:</label>
    <input type="phone" name="phone" ng-model="contacts.phone"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><input type="submit" value="Add Contact"></div>
</form>
</div>  
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        <td>{{contact.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">    </script>

<script>
var app = angular.module('contactApp', []);

app.controller('contactController', function($scope){
    $scope.contacts = {firstName:"Joe",email:"joe@gmail.com",phone:"453-367-9383"};
    console.log($scope.contact);
    $scope.contactsArray = [];
    $scope.addContact = function(contact){
        console.log(contact);
        //do whatever code you want....
       // $scope.contacts.push({firstName:'',email:'',phone:''});
       $scope.contactsArray.push(contact);//pushing your object here
       $scope.contacts = {};// for empty after submit
    };

});
</script>
```